# Get the width and height of the uploaded image using JCrop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Jcrop in javascript and I want to get the height and width of the selected image file. Can anyone help me?

```
function fileSelectHandler_assistant() {
    // get selected file
    var oFile = $('#ass-photo-file')[0].files[0]

    // check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
    var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;

    if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        $('.error').html('<button id="crop_alert_message_button" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed).').show();
        return;
    }
}
```